# Adding "indentation markers" (similar to what some IDEs / text editors can do)

Tags: formatting

Assume I have the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}
\begin{addmargin}[2\parindent]{0em}
    expand A
    \begin{addmargin}[2\parindent]{0em}
        expand B
        \begin{addmargin}[2\parindent]{0em}
            expand C
            \begin{addmargin}[2\parindent]{0em}
                expand D
            \end{addmargin}
            expand E
            \begin{addmargin}[2\parindent]{0em}
                expand F
            \end{addmargin}
            expand G
        \end{addmargin}
        expand H
        \begin{addmargin}[2\parindent]{0em}
            expand I
        \end{addmargin}
        expand J
        \begin{addmargin}[2\parindent]{0em}
            expand K\\
            expand L\\
            expand M
            \begin{addmargin}[2\parindent]{0em}
                expand N\\
                expand O\\
                expand P
            \end{addmargin}
        \end{addmargin}
    \end{addmargin}
\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

which when typeset looks like this:

[image]

Now, I want my output to have indent markers, something like the tiny dashed lines you see here.

[image]

I know that some environments for algorithms / pseudo-code offer this functionality, but all I want is plain text. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a command that shifts right a specified width, a specified number of times, and each time prints an indentation mark.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\shiftwidth}
\setlength{\shiftwidth}{2em}

% Draw vertical rule for indentation marker
%   You could also use, e.g., 0.75\baselineskip for the height
\newcommand{\indentmarker}{%
        \rule{0.4pt}{2ex}
}

% Draw rule and shift right by \shiftwidth 
\newcommand{\markindent}{%
    \indentmarker\hspace*{\shiftwidth}%
}

% Shift right and print indentation mark specified number of times 
\newcounter{shiftlevel}

\newcommand{\shift}[1]{%
    \setcounter{shiftlevel}{#1}
    \loop
        \markindent
        \addtocounter{shiftlevel}{-1}
    \ifnum\value{shiftlevel} > 0
    \repeat%
}

\begin{document}
Level One

\shift{1} Level Two

\shift{2} Level Three

\shift{2} More at this level

\shift{1} Level Two

Level One
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might ask a separate question would be how to wrap text at each level (like auto-indent in `vim`), if that is desired.